# How to distinguish click of modal dialog with the background in twitterbootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want click event to be distinguished between the click on modal dialog with the click of the background of modal dialog for some purpose.

Please help !

Thanks a ton in advance.

Comment: and there's some reason you can't simply use the event target?

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle with something you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any built in function to obtain what you want; the only "hacky" way I found is to check the click/keyup event of the `document` and if the modal is opened call your callback.

Code:

```
$(document).keyup(function (e) {
    if (e.which == 27 && $('body').hasClass('modal-open')) {
        console.log('esc')
    }
})

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if (e.target === $('.modal-scrollable')[0] && $('body').hasClass('modal-open')) {
        console.log('click')
    }
})
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/4zzKz/